# PowershellやC#からクリップボード転送時にExternalExceptionが頻発する原因と対策

Tags: c#, powershell

Windows 10でPowershellやC#でクリップボードにテキストを転送すると、`要求されたクリップボード操作に成功しませんでした。`例外が発生することがあります。
例外は発生するもののテキストはクリップボードに転送されています。

この現象はどのような要因が発生原因と考えられるでしょうか。また、原因調査はどのように行うべきでしょうか。
(空のcatchによる例外スキップ以外で)コーディングや設定による解決方法はあるでしょうか。

例外発生のトリガーになりそうな要因は不明です。
クリップボードを占有するアプリケーションや、クリップボード履歴ソフトなどは使用していないはずです。
PCを立ち上げて作業を続けていると突然発生することが多いです。
1度例外が発生すると、それ以降は再起動するまで上記の例外が頻発します。
長時間Excelを立ち上げていると発生率が高くなる気がしますが、統計は取っていません。

[本家SOの類似質問](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583642/determine-which-process-is-locking-the-clipboard)の回答を参考に、クリップボードを使用しているプロセス名を調べたところ、`Idle`と表示されました。

**Powershellサンプルコードと実行時出力**

```
PS C:\> "hoge" | Set-Clipboard
Set-Clipboard : 要求されたクリップボード操作に成功しませんでした。
発生場所 行:1 文字:10
+ "hoge" | Set-Clipboard
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-Clipboard], ExternalException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetClipboardCommand
```

**C#サンプルコード**

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var p = GetProcessLockingClipboard();
            if (p != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(p.ProcessName); // "Idle"が出力される
            }
            try
            {
                Clipboard.SetText("fuga");
            }catch(ExternalException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr GetOpenClipboardWindow();

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out int lpdwProcessId);

        private static Process GetProcessLockingClipboard()
        {
            int processId;
            GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetOpenClipboardWindow(), out processId);

            return Process.GetProcessById(processId);
        }
    }
}
```

**C#実行時出力**

```
Idle
System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException (0x800401D0): 要求されたクリップボード操作に成功しませ んでした。
   場所 System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.ThrowIfFailed(Int32 hr)
   場所 System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetDataObject(Object data, Boolean copy, Int32 retryTimes, Int32 retryDelay)
   場所 System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(String text, TextDataFormat format)
   場所 System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(String text)
   場所 ConsoleApplication7.Program.Main(String[] args) 場所 c:\users\payaneco\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication7\ConsoleApplication7\Program.cs:行 20
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard のソースコード](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Clipboard.cs)を確認してみると、
[OleSetClipboard](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/ole2/nf-ole2-olesetclipboard)と[OleFlushClipboard](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/ole2/nf-ole2-oleflushclipboard)というOle32.dllのWin32 APIを実行していることがわかります。

これらの関数で戻り値0x800401D0は、CLIPBRD_E_CANT_OPENが対応しています。
これは内部で[OpenClipboard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/cc430068.aspx)の実行に失敗したことを意味します。
この関数が失敗するパターンは、他の誰かがクリップボードを開いているときです。

おそらく他のアプリケーションで、
ちょうどクリップボードの確認をするような処理が発生したのだと思います。
これは意外と頻繁に発生します。

そこで System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard では、
裏でこっそりリトライしています。
SetText()なら100ms間隔で10回リトライしています。

直接 SetDataObject() を呼び出せば、このリトライ回数を調整することができます。
例えばリトライ回数を15回に増やすのであれば、

```
Clipboard.SetDataObject("fuga", true, 15, 100);
```

というような書き方が可能です。
環境に合わせて色々と調整してみてはいかがでしょうか。