# Windows10 でクリップボード内容から 指定文字列を簡単に削除する方法はありますか？

Tags: windows

**最終的にやりたいこと**
(Google Map 埋め込みで)指定文字列だけをなるべく簡単に抽出したい
[Google Map 埋め込みたいURL](https://www.google.com/maps/place/%E6%9D%B1%E4%BA%AC%E9%A7%85/@35.6812362,139.7649361,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x60188bfbd89f700b:0x277c49ba34ed38!8m2!3d35.6812362!4d139.7671248)

---

**前提**
クリップボード内容

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3240.8280303808788!2d139.76493611525882!3d35.68123618019432!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x60188bfbd89f700b%3A0x277c49ba34ed38!2z5p2x5Lqs6aeF!5e0!3m2!1sja!2sjp!4v1622174082623!5m2!1sja!2sjp" width="600" height="450" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy"></iframe>
```

**やりたいこと**
クリップボード内容から下記指定文字列をなるべく簡単に削除したい

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=

" width="600" height="450" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy"></iframe>
```

**クリップボードから(指定文字列を削除することで)抽出したい内容**

```
!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3240.8280303808788!2d139.76493611525882!3d35.68123618019432!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x60188bfbd89f700b%3A0x277c49ba34ed38!2z5p2x5Lqs6aeF!5e0!3m2!1sja!2sjp!4v1622174082623!5m2!1sja!2sjp
```

Comment: この記事[PowershellやC#からクリップボード転送時にExternalExceptionが頻発する原因と対策](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/47269/26370)のようにPowerShell/C#/Win32APIでクリップボードのデータを取り扱えるようですので、調べてみてはどうでしょう？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コメントに書いたように、[秀丸エディタで、選択範囲から指定文字列を削除するマクロを作りたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/76140/26370)の回答に書いた内容と、以下の辺の記事を基に：
[PowerShellメモ　クリップボード操作](https://qiita.com/Kosen-amai/items/2e92c9b1dc19fd12b6f5)
[about_Regular_Expressions](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7.1)
[正規表現での置換](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/standard/base-types/substitutions-in-regular-expressions)
[正規表現言語 - クイック リファレンス](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference)
[Powershellでの高度な置換](https://qiita.com/acuo/items/a4f83d886c4b8a7fcf52)

PowerShellでこんな処理で出来るでしょう。

```
$iframe = Get-Clipboard -Format Text
$value = $iframe -replace '<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed\?pb=(.*?)" .*?</iframe>', '$1'
Set-Clipboard $value
```

例えばその前にクリップボードにテキストを設定する行を挿入して検証出来ます。

```
Set-Clipboard '<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3240.8280303808788!2d139.76493611525882!3d35.68123618019432!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x60188bfbd89f700b%3A0x277c49ba34ed38!2z5p2x5Lqs6aeF!5e0!3m2!1sja!2sjp!4v1622174082623!5m2!1sja!2sjp" width="600" height="450" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy"></iframe>'
$iframe = Get-Clipboard -Format Text
$value = $iframe -replace '<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed\?pb=(.*?)" .*?</iframe>', '$1'
Set-Clipboard $value
```

---

C#なら、この辺のクラスを使うことで同様のことが出来るのでは？
[System.Windows.Clipboard クラス](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.windows.clipboard?view=net-5.0)
[System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard クラス](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.clipboard?view=net-5.0)
[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex クラス](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=net-5.0)

Comment: PowerShellでクリップボード操作できるのですね。早速試してみたら、期待した通り、動作しました。