# 秀丸エディタで、選択範囲から指定文字列を削除するマクロを作りたい

Tags: エディタ

秀丸エディタで、選択範囲から指定文字列を削除するマクロを作りたいのですが、参考になりそうなURLはありませんか？

---

**前提**
選択範囲

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3240.8280303808788!2d139.76493611525882!3d35.68123618019432!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x60188bfbd89f700b%3A0x277c49ba34ed38!2z5p2x5Lqs6aeF!5e0!3m2!1sja!2sjp!4v1622174082623!5m2!1sja!2sjp" width="600" height="450" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy"></iframe>
```

**やりたいこと**
選択範囲から下記指定文字列を削除するマクロを作りたい

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=

" width="600" height="450" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy"></iframe>
```

**選択範囲から(指定文字列を削除することで)抽出したい内容**

```
!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3240.8280303808788!2d139.76493611525882!3d35.68123618019432!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x60188bfbd89f700b%3A0x277c49ba34ed38!2z5p2x5Lqs6aeF!5e0!3m2!1sja!2sjp!4v1622174082623!5m2!1sja!2sjp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

この辺の記事が参考になるでしょう。

公式ヘルプ全体
[秀丸エディタヘルプ目次（Ver8.97対応版）](https://help.maruo.co.jp/hidemaru/html/010_Intro.html)
[秀丸エディタ マクロ言語ヘルプ目次（Ver8.97対応版）](https://help.maruo.co.jp/hidemac/html/010_Intro.html)
[秀丸エディタ マクロ言語（入門用）ヘルプ目次（Ver8.95対応版）](https://help.maruo.co.jp/be_hidemac/html/01_Index.html)

マクロでの置換処理の解説記事その１
[秀丸：秀丸マクロでの置換](http://vip-audio.jugem.jp/?eid=44)

マクロでの置換処理の解説記事その２
[秀丸マクロ: 置換](https://step-learn.com/article/hidemaru-macro/replece.html)
[秀丸マクロ: 文字列を置換する自作関数](https://step-learn.com/article/hidemaru-macro/p-replace.html)
[Replace関数を作ってみた](http://officetanaka.net/other/hidemaru/10.htm)

処理の目的は違うけれども、まとまったマクロの例
[tableタグを作る 2](https://www.jepa.or.jp/nl/kowaza/010.html)

---

とりあえずマクロではなく手動での処理であれば、対象範囲を選択した後で検索メニューの置換処理を選択してダイアログを表示し、以下の指定をすれば出来るでしょう。
空白文字の数とか、URLの先頭部分の文字列に変動があるなら、それ相応の正規表現を指定してください。

検索(S)：

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed\?pb=(.*?)" .*?</iframe>
```

置換(E)：

```
\1
```

選択した範囲はあらかじめチェックがついているはず。
正規表現にチェックを付ける。
対象範囲が複数行にわたる場合は、検索文字列入力欄右の`▶`メニューで複数行にチェックを付ける。